# Values of two columns pulling on separate rows. How do I get data on same row?

Tags: sql, oracle

SQL through Oracle:

My current query output formats as follows:

```
Date ----- Value1 ------ Value2
Jan 1 ------- 7
Jan 1 ------------------------  10
Jan 2 ------- 12
Jan 2 ------------------------ 30
```

I want value1 and value2 to pull on the same date.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this through aggregation:

```
select date, max(value1) as value1, max(value2) as value2
from (<your query here>) q
group by date;
```